Adding non-ArcGIS Rest service to QGIS
I've been trying to work out how to request the data for planning applications from the opendata available from a council into QGIS for being able to set my own search parameters and do some analysis on the location of planning proposals and potential impacts on environmental factors.
However, I don't know coding (but would like to learn) and I'm not proficient enough to understand how I utilise this https://restservices.herefordshire.gov.uk/opendata/services/planningapplicationsservice. I want to get the spatial data I can view online on the council's webmap and look at the data in QGIS. I'm ok adding ArcGIS Rest services and general WFS/WMS layers, but I've spent ages trying to figure it out and what things are in terms of APIs, Rest, json etc but I'm lost and it's beyond me.
How can I access this data?

You cannot connect QGIS directly to these REST services (which return the data as a json structure). If you don't know coding, I would recommend you to user the Webmap you provided as a link, select the data that you want and then export the data: download the results as CSV files. Then import the data into QGIS as a CSV layers (see tutorials/GIS SE questions for that)

To get GeoJSON back for an application you need to request it.
(Random) Example:
https://restservices.herefordshire.gov.uk/planningV2/application/242581/geojson?callback=jQuery32107880159576218448_1729630488359&_=1729630488360
Which will return
jQuery32108695683097130928_1729630393698({"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-2.750844372,52.084684095],[-2.750844423,52.084683147],[-2.750844608,52.084682205],[-2.750844925,52.084681277],[-2.750845372,52.084680369],[-2.750845946,52.084679489],[-2.750846642,52.084678643],[-2.750847454,52.084677838],[-2.750848378,52.084677079],[-2.750849405,52.084676373],[-2.750850528,52.084675725],[-2.750851738,52.084675139],[-2.750853026,52.084674621],[-2.750854383,52.084674175],[-2.750855798,52.084673803],[-2.750857259,52.084673508],[-2.750858757,52.084673293],[-2.75086028,52.08467316],[-2.750861815,52.084673108],[-2.750863352,52.08467314],[-2.750864879,52.084673254],[-2.750866383,52.08467345],[-2.750867855,52.084673726],[-2.750869281,52.08467408],[-2.750870653,52.084674509],[-2.750871958,52.084675011],[-2.750873188,52.08467558],[-2.750874332,52.084676214],[-2.750875383,52.084676907],[-2.750876331,52.084677654],[-2.750877171,52.084678448],[-2.750877895,52.084679285],[-2.750878498,52.084680158],[-2.750878976,52.08468106],[-2.750879324,52.084681984],[-2.750879541,52.084682923],[-2.750879624,52.084683871],[-2.750879573,52.084684819],[-2.750879388,52.084685761],[-2.750879071,52.084686689],[-2.750878623,52.084687597],[-2.75087805,52.084688477],[-2.750877354,52.084689323],[-2.750876541,52.084690128],[-2.750875617,52.084690887],[-2.75087459,52.084691593],[-2.750873467,52.084692241],[-2.750872257,52.084692826],[-2.750870969,52.084693344],[-2.750869612,52.084693791],[-2.750868198,52.084694163],[-2.750866736,52.084694458],[-2.750865238,52.084694673],[-2.750863716,52.084694806],[-2.75086218,52.084694857],[-2.750860643,52.084694826],[-2.750859117,52.084694712],[-2.750857612,52.084694516],[-2.750856141,52.08469424],[-2.750854714,52.084693886],[-2.750853343,52.084693457],[-2.750852037,52.084692955],[-2.750850808,52.084692385],[-2.750849663,52.084691752],[-2.750848613,52.084691059],[-2.750847664,52.084690312],[-2.750846824,52.084689517],[-2.7508461,52.08468868],[-2.750845497,52.084687808],[-2.750845019,52.084686906],[-2.750844671,52.084685982],[-2.750844455,52.084685043],[-2.750844372,52.084684095]]],[[[-2.750917885,52.084755352],[-2.750917934,52.084754451],[-2.75091811,52.084753556],[-2.750918412,52.084752674],[-2.750918838,52.084751811],[-2.750919384,52.084750975],[-2.750920047,52.08475017],[-2.750920821,52.084749405],[-2.7509217,52.084748684],[-2.750922678,52.084748013],[-2.750923748,52.084747397],[-2.7509249,52.084746841],[-2.750926127,52.084746348],[-2.750927419,52.084745924],[-2.750928766,52.08474557],[-2.750930157,52.08474529],[-2.750931584,52.084745086],[-2.750933033,52.084744959],[-2.750934496,52.08474491],[-2.750935959,52.08474494],[-2.750937413,52.084745049],[-2.750938846,52.084745235],[-2.750940247,52.084745497],[-2.750941605,52.084745833],[-2.750942911,52.084746241],[-2.750944154,52.084746718],[-2.750945325,52.084747259],[-2.750946414,52.084747862],[-2.750947415,52.08474852],[-2.750948318,52.08474923],[-2.750949118,52.084749985],[-2.750949807,52.084750781],[-2.750950382,52.08475161],[-2.750950836,52.084752467],[-2.750951168,52.084753345],[-2.750951374,52.084754238],[-2.750951453,52.084755139],[-2.750951404,52.08475604],[-2.750951228,52.084756935],[-2.750950926,52.084757817],[-2.7509505,52.08475868],[-2.750949954,52.084759516],[-2.750949291,52.08476032],[-2.750948517,52.084761086],[-2.750947638,52.084761807],[-2.75094666,52.084762478],[-2.750945591,52.084763094],[-2.750944438,52.08476365],[-2.750943211,52.084764143],[-2.75094192,52.084764567],[-2.750940573,52.084764921],[-2.750939181,52.084765201],[-2.750937755,52.084765405],[-2.750936305,52.084765532],[-2.750934843,52.084765581],[-2.750933379,52.084765551],[-2.750931925,52.084765442],[-2.750930493,52.084765256],[-2.750929092,52.084764994],[-2.750927733,52.084764658],[-2.750926427,52.08476425],[-2.750925184,52.084763773],[-2.750924013,52.084763232],[-2.750922924,52.084762629],[-2.750921923,52.084761971],[-2.75092102,52.084761261],[-2.750920221,52.084760506],[-2.750919531,52.08475971],[-2.750918957,52.084758881],[-2.750918502,52.084758024],[-2.75091817,52.084757146],[-2.750917964,52.084756253],[-2.750917885,52.084755352]]]]},"properties":{"appid":"P242581/J","siteaddress":"1 South Cottages Jasmine Lane Burghill Hereford Herefordshire HR4 7QT","apptype":"Works to trees covered by TPO","status":"Valid","dtevalid":"2024-10-09T00:00:00.000Z","appdesc":"Remove two oak trees. Trees numbered 1 to 8 are all mature oaks. Trees1 and 2 constitute a risk to life. Removal of these trees would lessenthe immediate danger to anyone in the cottage or in the gardens, and  provide more light to the gardens whilst the amenity value would be   unaffected as there would still be six oaks in the garden. No works totrees 3 - 8.\r","rawid":"242581","parishdesc":"Burghill","warddesc":"Queenswood","application_url":"https://www.herefordshire.gov.uk/info/200142/planning_services/planning_application_search/details?id=242581","decndesc":"","total":1}})

This can be loaded into QGIS (3.38 used)

Thank you Mapperz! That's really helped. I can at least add individual applications via their reference number and then add them into QGIS. Is there a way to request features within a certain area/bounding box? Thanks again

Myles Haynes has created a Geodatadownloader that allows you to download ESRI Rest Services in a variety of spatial data formats supported in QGIS.
https://geodatadownloader.com/maps/create

The REST service linked in the question is not an Esri service.
